# ¿Cómo crear un max heap en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

En Python3 tenemos la habilidad de crear un min heap con [heapq](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/heapq.html) pero no hay algo en la librería de Python que puede simular un max heap. ¿Cómo podemos simular un max heap?

Comment: ¿Por qué no multiplicas los valores por -1? Sólo si es un heap númerico, claro. También tienes la función [heapq._heapify_max(x)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f917c243c52d62a787738379fb9b97acbed02c17/Lib/heapq.py#L196) que te permite convertirlo en un maxheap.

Comment: ¡Genial! Lo haré. Gracias :]